# Shopware 6 Storefront Login with Store API

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app, shopware6-api

I am building a Shopware 6 app that creates guest sessions utilizing a 3rd party service to retrieve the address. When I use the Store API `/account/register` endpoint the context token changes so the shopper is left with an empty session when redirected back to the Shopware storefront.

Is there any way to assign the new context token to the shopper's session?